# Usage of boolean .env variables with v-if conditional

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3. I have started a vite project. My component has a div v-if condition which does restrict the page from displaying some buttons if the env variables are true and false.

This is the part of the component.

```
<div v-if="mePrivate == true && mePublic == false">
              <v-chip class="ma-2" color="success" @click="deposit(row.ticker, row.address)">
                <v-icon left>mdi-server-plus</v-icon>Deposit
              </v-chip>
              <v-chip class="ma-2" color="red" dark @click="showWithdrawOverlay(row.ticker)">
                <v-icon left>mdi-server-plus</v-icon>Withdraw
              </v-chip>
</div>
<div v-else>
```

The mePrivate and mePublic variables are declared below in the script section which are being declared in a `.env` file

```
export default {
  components: { QrcodeVue },
  props: [ 'wallets' ],
  data: function() {
    return {
      mePrivate: process.env.ME_PRIVATE,
      mePublic: process.env.ME_PUBLIC,
```

In my .env file I have these env variables declared properly meeting the condition as true and false. However the buttons are still not being rendered

**P.S I have tried declaring true and false as strings as well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thoroughly read the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) as this is where all the info in my answer comes from.

The simplest case is to have a `.env` file in your project's root directory (NOT `/src`, although you can always customize the location with a [config option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envdir))

Then for any env variable that should be accessible to client side code, prefix the name with "VITE_", e.g. `VITE_ME_PRIVATE=true`

This env variable can then be used in your code as `import.meta.env.VITE_ME_PRIVATE`

Here's another important note though specific to your use case: **environment variables can only be strings**, not booleans or other types.  If you want a boolean env, just know something like `VITE_ME_PRIVATE=false` will return as the string value "false".

A simple equality comparison can do the conversion for you:

```js
data() {
  return {
    mePrivate: import.meta.env.VITE_ME_PRIVATE === 'true',
    mePublic: import.meta.env.VITE_ME_PUBLIC === 'true',
  }
}
```

Comment: The env is in root of the project and the prefix is VITE_VUE of course. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

When you started your Vue3 project do you used **Vite** or **Vue CLI**

If **Vite** you have to define your env variables in `vite.config.js` file like so:

```
 define: { 'process.env': {myPublic : true, myPrivate : false} },
```

and in your page in the script define the variables

```
const myPublic = process.env.myPublic
const myPrivate = process.env.myPrivate
```

then use it in the template

```
<template>
    <div>
        myPublic is: {{myPublic}}
        myPrivate is: {{myPrivate}}
    </div>
</template>
```

---

but if you are using **Vue CLI** I believe that you should install `vue/cli-service` package

and edit `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
}
```

After that this code should work properly

```
<script>
    const myPublic = process.env.myPublic
    const myPrivate = process.env.myPrivate
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        myPublic is: {{myPublic}}
        myPrivate is: {{myPrivate}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Would it work as `<div v-if:>` ?

Comment: I started my project with vite. I have defined the following in vite config.

`define: {
    'process.env': {
      VITE_VUE_APP_MMBOTURL: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_MMBOTURL,
      VITE_VUE_APP_MENAME: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_MENAME,
      VITE_VUE_APP_WEBHOST: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_WEBHOST,
      VITE_VUE_APP_MMBOTHOST: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_MMBOTHOST,
      VITE_VUE_APP_MMBOTPORT: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_MMBOTPORT,
      VITE_VUE_APP_ME_PRIVATE: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_ME_PRIVATE,
      VITE_VUE_APP_ME_PUBLIC: process.env.VITE_VUE_APP_ME_PUBLIC`

Comment: I have a seperate .env file which has got the variable values

Comment: This answer does not follow the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) on how to use env variables at all.